# Cluster items in vis.js timeline via Streamlit component

Tags: streamlit, vis.js-timeline

I am trying to cluster items within the vis.js timeline streamlit implementation

[Github repo](https://github.com/giswqs/streamlit-timeline)

[Streamlit component overview](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/new-component-streamlit-timeline-creating-beautiful-timelines-with-bi-directional-communication/31804)

I am rendering about 20k items and therefore would like to use the "cluster" option described at the documentation of vis.js timeline
[vis.js timeline docu](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/)

I am trying to cluster items with the following code but nothing happens.

```
`from streamlit_timeline import st_timeline

items = [
    {"id": 1, "start": "2023-05-01", "end": "2023-05-09", "group": 3},
    {"id": 2, "start": "2023-05-06", "end": "2023-05-12", "group": 3}
]

st_timeline(items=items, 
            groups=[], 
            height=200, 
            options={
              "cluster": {"showStipes": True, "maxItems": 5}
            }
)`
```

I tried to play around with the formatting of the option such as put the True into a string ("true") etc. but all tries failed so far.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance!